# почему нельзя после использования ф-ии map в роутере писать код?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history =  createBrowserHistory();

const page = function(text){return(<div>{text}</div>)}


class People extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    // this.self = this.bind(this);
}; 
componentDidMount(){

}

render(){
    var people = this.props.people;
    var ul;
    return (<div><Router history={history}>
        <div>
    {ul = this.props.people.map((item,i)=>{
                    var k = Object.keys(item)
                    k = k[0]
                    var li;

                     li = <li key={i}><Link to ={k.toLowerCase().trim().replace(" ","-")} >{k}</Link> </li>;
                    console.log(k);

                    return li;})
    console.log('descriptions');

}
    </div></Router></div>)

}
}

export default People;
```

выдает ошибку синтаксиса, не пойму, вроде бы нормально все, может я не понимаю концептуально чего-то, как работает код, какая-то деталь.

> Failed to compile ./src/People.js Syntax error:
>   C:/Users/Dima/Desktop/myReact/my-app/src/People.js: Unexpected token,
>   expected } (36:2)

```
34 |                        
  35 |                      return li;})
> 36 |      console.log('descriptions');
     |      ^
  37 | 
  38 |  }
  39 |      </div></Router></div>)
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос или весь код, или хотя бы ошибку, а лучше и то и другое.

Comment: Мне кажется, что тут проблема в том, что вы присваиваете переменной возвращенный `html`, а потом пытаетесь внутри разметки еще и вызвать `console.log('descriptions');`. В данном случае это не колбэк, а просто js-код в разметке без необходимых тегов.
Что вы вообще хотите сделать? Может оно там совсем не к месту?

Comment: В итоге должен получится компонент, который может перебрать массив и сделать из него меню ссылок на страницы(это то, что в переменной ul )и после объявления этой переменной должны следовать роуты,собственно и позволяющие переход по ссылкам.

Comment: Не могу найти вообще каких-либо упоминаний о написании функций после `map`, но подозреваю, что проблема в том, что `jsx` особым способом преобразует объекты, что вызывает синтаксические ошибки.  
Посмотрите в документации, мне кажется, что это то, что вы и хотите сделать: 
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config  
Вот похожая статья на русском: https://habrahabr.ru/post/329996/ и https://codepen.io/pshrmn/pen/YZXZqM

Comment: Спасибо за ответ Илья, то что было нужно.